# Slurmdbd and ssl

Tags: mysql, ssl, mariadb, slurm

I am trying to setup slurm with a remote mariadb database for accounting on Azure, using a mariadb database as service.

If ssl is disabled slurmdbd is perfectly working, it is able to contact the database and append new jobs.

If I enable ssl on the database, I got this error:

```
slurmdbd: debug2: Attempting to connect to mariadb.database.azure.com:3306
slurmdbd: error: mysql_real_connect failed: 9002 SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.
```

I am perfectly able to connect to the database using:

```
mysql --host=<host> --port=3306 --user=<user> --password=<password> --ssl --ssl-ca=./BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem
```

I tried to add:

```
[client]
ssl_ca = /etc/mysql/ssl/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem
```

to `/etc/my.cnf`, in this way I am able to connect (with ssl enabled) using only:

```
mysql --host=<host> --port=3306 --user=<user> --password=<password>
```

but slurmdbd gives me the same error.

Basically, I am not able to find the proper location for slurmdbd to read the ssl_ca.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i dont believe slurm has the ability to talk to an SSL Encrypted MySQL/MariaDB Server. You would need to set up a local MySQL Proxy which redirects the queries to the SSL connected one.

Comment: Looking at the https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/slurm.spec there is a ssl option but I do not understand if it on by default or it is just a typo.

Comment: Looks to not do anything in the spec file even if defined :/

Comment: I am hosting mysql on the network with traefik to get https and can connect to that url using ssl without specifying anything in extra in the config. It only have to be anbled in the mysql database as that will handle it all.